# UpdatePanel update without trigger button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have an UpdatePanel with ContentTemplate specified. When page loads, user can do some AJAX work in other part of the page. Then, after that work is finished, I would like to update only content inside UpdatePanel, but without pressing any buttons etc. I should be done automatically using JavaScript when previously started AJAX work finishes. How to do it without manual clicking on the trigger button?

EDIT:

Ok, I've followed that _doPostBack rule, and whole page is posted.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelAttachments" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    ........
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <input type="text" name="test" onchange="__doPostBack('<%=panelAttachments.UniqueID %>',''); return false;" />
</td>
```

Thanks, Pawel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To refresh an update panel from javascript:

`__doPostBack(updatePanelUniqueID,'');`

The first parameter is the UniqueID (not CientID) of the UpdatePanel.The 2nd parameter is optional arguments you can pass which will be available to your server code. Both are stored in hidden form fields by ASP.NET, you can access them in codebehind:

```
Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

But if you just want to refresh a panel and don't need to pass any additional info from the client, you can ignore then 2nd argument.

If you look at the HTML generated by ASP.NET for an async postback control, you'll see it's exactly this.

Comment: Could you show how that javascript would be called, for example from a text input TextChanged event?

Comment: `<asp:TextBox id="mytextbox" runat="server" onchange="__doPostBack('<%=myUpdatePanel.UniqueID %>','')" />`

Comment: Also, `TextChanged` is a server-side event, `onchange` is the client event for a textbox. `TextChanged` causes server code to be run after a postback. Note that the client event will fire as soon as focus leaves the textbox control. If this is what you want, the example is right, but when you say "after the work is finished" maybe you don't want it to happen every time any textbox is changed? You can add this hook to any client event you want, this may not be the best way for your situation.

Comment: Thx, I've followed that tip and nothing, whole page is posted instead of ajax - details in question.

Comment: You added a button, not a textbox control, so it's still going to submit. Add `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` and/or add `return false;` to the javascript: `onchange="__doPostBack('<%=myUpdatePanel.UniqueID %>',''); return false;"` which will cancel the default action of a control.

Comment: By the way -- the original question was how to do this *without* a button, if you're using a submit control, just let asp.net do it for you and put it in the UpdatePanel, that is the behavior by design. You can also explicitly register submit controls outside an update panel to do the same thing. You only need to put your own javascript into controls when you are trying to do things based on some other sequence of events or when not using a submit control.

Comment: Yeah, I just added a button to check it, sorry for confusion :) Ok, now I added code with that textbox. And stil whole page is posted. Perpahs it has something to do with my page: I dynamically add/remove user control etc...?

Comment: Could be. Is it possible that the `UpdatePanel` is not rendering after a postback? If asp.net can't find the control specified, I am pretty sure it does a full postback.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that with the TextBox you have in the question now, it's posting *when you leave the textbox* or when you click a submit control? I may have given you bad quotes, I bet the scriptlet isn't running: Change to this: `onchange='__doPostBack("<%=panelAttachments.UniqueID %>",""); return false;' />` (note switching single and double quotes). However if that was the case, then nothing should have happened when you leave the textbox control in your example.